# Error when installing package "crontab" on Beaglebone Black (Debian Buster)

Tags: cron, beagleboneblack

I am working on a project regarding autorunning a pythonscript on boot, on a Beaglebone Black Rev. C, running BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06.

I am trying to follow the first part of this tutorial (I will describe the steps below):
https://www.engineersgarage.com/autorun-python-script-on-beaglebone-black-boot-part-14-15/

The steps proposed in the turorial are:

1. SSH into the machine through PC
2. Install crontab using the command `sudo apt-get install crontab`
3. Open the crontab and edit using `crontab –e`
4. Add the line `@reboot sudo  python /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/PYTHONSCRIPT.py &`

From a screenshot in the tutorial, it seems that crontab should be installed in the same folder as where the python script is located.

Here is what I experienced when I tried to follow the steps:

Installing crontab, returned an error:

```
debian@beaglebone:/media/card$ cd /media/card/Tests
debian@beaglebone:/media/card/Tests$ sudo apt-get install crontab
[sudo] password for debian:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package crontab
```

There is a crontab file in the etc-folder. When listing the installed applications, using `apt list --installed`, I find the line below on the list:

```
cron/oldstable,now 3.0pl1-134+deb10u1 armhf [installed]
```

Also, perhaps I should create the `cron` job from the etc folder? Would there be any downsides to that?

My project is located in a folder located on an SD Card, although I have set it up so I can write to it. Does this complicate the operation?

(Please tell me if I need to provide further information - I will of course be happy to do so.)

Comment: Package list can be retrieved by : apt list --installed and crontab package is called cron (in ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

First I see your user need password, so using `sudo` in `cron` will involve entering password, which is not sample. Better just run:

```
sudo su -
```

and then

```
crontab -e
```

and inside enter

```
@reboot python /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/PYTHONSCRIPT.py
```

You do not need to install `cron` as I am 99.99% sure it is already installed. If its not check the comment above about the package name.

About running `python` scripts will be wise to set your user environment and then run the script. Just create sample script (`/PATH/TO/SCRIPT/runp.sh` for example)and run it in `cron`:

```
. /home/debian/.bashrc #or whatever is the path to your user
python /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/PYTHONSCRIPT.py
```

make the script executable and add in `cron` this:

```
@reboot  /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/runp.sh
```

BTW you do not need to add it in background as the script will be executed from cron till the end (of script)

And one more point: **do not use SD cards for operational storage**, they are unreliable.

Comment: Thanks, I think it may have worked. I will follow up later this week to maybe test somethiing simple with the flashing leds.